# Почему класс не срабатывает, ошибок никаких не выдаёт?

Tags: php, wordpress

Почему класс не срабатывает, ошибок никаких не выдаёт?

```
class Db_Optimize_Tables_Cron {
  public static function load() {
    add_action( 'init', array( __CLASS__, 'schedule_events' ) );
  }

  /**
   * Schedule cron events, runs during init.
   */
  public static function schedule_events() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'db_optimize_tables_cron' ) )
      // wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'db_optimize_tables_cron' );
      wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'db_optimize_tables_cron' );
      add_action( 'db_optimize_tables_cron', array( __CLASS__, 'optimize_tables' ) );
  }

  public static function optimize_tables() {
    global $wpdb;
    $bDebug = TRUE;
    $tables = $wpdb->get_col( "SHOW TABLES" );
    foreach ( $tables as $table ) {
      if ( $wpdb->query( "OPTIMIZE TABLE $table" ) !== FALSE ) {
        if ( $bDebug ) {
          error_log( "Db_Optimizer ran successfully on $table" );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Db_Optimize_Tables_Cron::load();
```

Comment: А если schedule_events сделать не статическим?  и в первой строке этой функции вызовите var_dump(1) чтобы понять отрабатывает или нет она

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код работает, я проверил в отладчике. Единственная ошибка - вместо `saotn_db_optimize_tables_cron` надо поставить `db_optimize_tables_cron`. Иначе событие добавляется при каждом обращении к сайту.

Comment: Я исправил и в вопросе и в коде, но в Scheduled Actions пусто!

Comment: Где и как вы запускаете этот файл? Поставьте этот код в function.php вашей темы.

Comment: Так он там и находится

Comment: Должен работать. Не знаю, где и как вы смотрите sheduled actions. Вот результат работы с вашим кодом: https://monosnap.com/file/VTBuxkm6H8pBkpGpv64X5Eun1q80LM

Comment: Вот тут - /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-status&tab=action-scheduler и тут смотрю - /wp-admin/tools.php?page=action-scheduler

Comment: Эти страницы показывают ТОЛЬКО акции WooCommerce. Используйте wp-cli или поставьте плагин WP Cron Events

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97313/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-spoilt).